# Exclude() method is not working for post method in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

I have tried adding `toJSON(){return classtoPlain(this)}` in my entity still its not working.
Here is my controller

```
@Controller('users')
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}
  @HttpCode(200)
  @Post()
  async create(@Body() user: User): Promise<User> {
    return await this.usersService.create(user).catch((err) => {
      throw new HttpException({ message: err.message }, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    });
  }
```

Here is my Entity

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Gender } from '../Constants/enum';
import { Exclude, instanceToPlain } from 'class-transformer';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName?: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: Gender,
  })
  gender: Gender;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column()
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  password: string;

  constructor(partial: Partial<User>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
  toJSON() {
    return instanceToPlain(this);
  }
}
```

Here is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly user_detailsRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
  create(user: User) {
    return this.user_detailsRepository.save(user);
  }
```

I have tried many solutions but still nothing works.
For GET its working but for post its showing the password field.If any one can provide any solution it would be great.

Answer (score -2):

You're mixing between Entity definition/validation, which typeORM functions/decorators (in your case) should handle. And DTO definition, which class-transformer/validator should handle

So you should define a `createUserDTO.ts` file like below, and use it as in the controller/service file:

```
export class createUserDTO {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  firstName: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  lastName?: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(Gender)
  gender: Gender;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  email: string;

  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  password: string;

}
```

The entity file shouldn't have the password column (just omit the field completely), should look like this:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName?: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: Gender,
  })
  gender: Gender;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;
}
```

Then, when you call `return this.user_detailsRepository.save(userDto);`, it should work fine

Comment: But if I will completely omit the Column from entity file then how a column will be created in the database?

Comment: It won't be created in the DB.

From where do you want to exclude the `password` field?

Comment: I just want to exclude it from the json response this command this.user_detailsRepository.save(user) returns every field in the response

Comment: ok, it wasn't clear.

The safe way i would do it is to receive the DB response of `.create(user)` and manipulate to some other object (UserCreateResponseDto for example). Here's an example:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly user_detailsRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
  create(user: User) {
    const user = this.user_detailsRepository.save(user);
    return UserService.transformEntityToDto(user)
  }

  private static transformEntityToDto(user: User): CreateUserResponseDto {
   transform.
}  
```